# Why does my cylinder turns into a plane in cloth animation

Tags: animation

I made a long cylinder directly from 'shift+A' as a cotton rope, then divided it into 10 parts and applied 'cloth' modifier. But it turns into plane later in the animation. I have no idea about what's wrong with my modeling.

I also tried to make a plane and then use 'solidify' to give the thickness. But it also turns out to be a plane.

Here is the animation of that cylinder.
[image: cylinder turns into a plane]

How to prevent the cylinder from being a plane? I want to make a falling rope.

Thanks.

Comment: Cloth is a thin material that deforms easily. I think what you want is soft body where you can set the  [stiffness of the edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/settings.html#soft-body-edges) to define how much the shape deforms.

Answer (score 1):

So, it is quite simple, you dont tell blender what is the physic of your rope. A cynlindre with cloth simulation is like an empty cylindre made of fabric.

If you want to create a rope simulation, you will need to apply the simulation on a line and not a cylindre, then draw a cylindre around the line.

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg7jxAMs60Q) that could help you to achieve what you want.